# Functions of bounded variation on all $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: measure-theory, integration, bounded-variation

Consider $F:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that 
 $\sup_{a,b}T_F (a,b)<\infty$ where $T_F (a,b)$ is the total variation of $F$ on the interval $[a,b]$. Then we have

i) $\int_\mathbb{R}|F(x+h)-F(x)|dx\leq A |h| $, for some constant $A$ and $\forall h\in \mathbb{R}$;

ii)$\int_\mathbb{R}F(x)\phi'(x)dx\leq A $ whenever $\phi \in C^1$ with compact support and $|\phi|_\infty\leq 1$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- We can write for $h\neq 0$, using Fubini's theorem for non-negative functions that 
  \begin{align}
  \int_{\mathbb R}|f(x+h)-f(x)|dx&=\sum_{j\in\mathbb Z}\int_{j|h|}^{(j+1)|h|}|f(x+h)-f(x)|dx\\\
  &=\sum_{j\in\mathbb Z}\int_0^{|h|}|f(x+(j+1)h)-f(x+jh)|dx\\\
  &=\int_0^{|h|}\sum_{j\in\mathbb Z}|f(x+(j+1)h)-f(x+jh)|dx.
  \end{align}
  For integers $M$ and $N$ and $x\in\Bbb R$, we have $$\sum_{j=-N}^M |f(x+(j+1)h)-f(x+jh)|\leqslant T_F(x-Nh,x+(M+1)h)\leqslant \sup_{a,b\in\mathbb R}T_F(a,b),$$
  because we took the subdivision $x+jh,-N\leqslant j\leqslant M$ of $[x-Mh,x+(M+1)h]$.
  We conclude that $\int_{\mathbb R}|f(x+h)-f(x)|dx\leqslant |h|\sup_{a,b\in\mathbb R}T_F(a,b)$.
- Put $f_n(x)=F(x)n(\phi(x+n^{-1})-\phi(x))$ and check that we have the hypothesis to apply the dominated convergence theorem. We get 
  \begin{align*}
  \int_{\mathbb R}F(x)\phi'(x)dx&=\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{\mathbb R}nF(x)(\phi(x+n^{-1})-\phi(x))dx\\\
  &=\lim_{n\to \infty}n\int_{\mathbb R}(F(x-n^{-1})-F(x))\phi(x)dx\\\
  &\leqslant \limsup_{n\to\infty}n\int_{\mathbb R}|F(x-n^{-1})-F(x)|\cdot |\phi(x)|dx\\\
  &\leqslant \sup_{a,b\in\mathbb R}T_F(a,b) \mbox{ by the first step}.
  \end{align*}

Comment: I couldn't get the gap in the last equality. I could not see also how to dominate that sequence.

Comment: I think I got it you use the Intermediate Value theorem on $\phi$ right?

Comment: The domination is clear the problem is the last equality since $F\phi$ is not absolutely continuous.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo, Could you please elaborate this one, I am having a hard time to follow this "Since for integers $M$ and $N$ we have $$\sum_{j=-N}^M |f(x+(j+1)h)-f(x+jh)|\leq T_F(-Mh,(N+2)h)\leq \sup_{a,b\in\mathbb R}T_F(a,b)$$"

Comment: @Deepak My previous estimate didn't take account of $x$. Now I've corrected.

Comment: But still, I am in confusion. Can you explain further please? @DavideGiraudo

Comment: @DavideGiraudo $$\sum_{j=-N}^M |f(x+(j+1)h)-f(x+jh)|\leqslant T_F(x-Mh,x+(N+2)h)$$
 Would not that $N+2$ must be $N+1$ then? or are you trying to bound by finer partition?

Comment: Now this make lot more sense. Thanks @DavideGiraudo.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo how can we draw the link between the $\sum_{j=-N}^M$ and $\sum_{j\in\mathbb Z}$ ? In other words, how would we show that it generalizes to infinity? Because the partial sums converge then the series converges right?

Comment: If a sequence of non-negative real numbers $(a_n)$ is such that there exists a constant $C$ for which for all $N, M$, $\sum_{k=M}^Na_k\leqslant C$, then $\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}a_k\leqslant C$.

Comment: how are we dominating the $f_n$ sequence for D.C.T?

Comment: @DavideGiraudo In addition, i know that a change of variables was invoked in this line $=\lim_{n\to \infty}n\int_{\mathbb R}(F(x-n^{-1})-F(x))\phi(x)dx$ However, why was it that one $\varphi$ disappeared and $F$ appeared?

Comment: $f_n(x)$ can be bounded by $\lvert F(x)\rVert \sup_{t\in\mathbb R}\lvert \phi'(x)\rVert $ and the last supremum is finite since $\phi$ has a  compact support. For you second question, I splitted the integral into two parts, and do the substitution $t=x+n^{-1}$.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo I can't upvote this enough! To add to your response, can we show that $F(x)$ is integrable?

Comment: @DavideGiraudo at this point it is not clear that $F(x)$ is integrable however could we use the bounded convergence theorem instead?