# Prove that $\sin x$ is not of bounded variation, $\sin x\not\in BV$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I already know that $\sin x\in BV([a,b])$ for $-\infty<a<b<\infty$.

However, I have failed to see why $\sin x\notin BV$.   Please help.

Comment: What you have tried  ?

Comment: Did you tries to separate intervals ? for example $(0,\frac{\pi}{2}) ,(\frac{\pi}{2},\pi),...$?

Comment: Hint: $f(x) = \sin(x)$ is periodic and non constant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint. Let $x_n = \frac{\pi(2n + 1)}{2}$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Then $\{x_n\}$ is a strictly increasing sequence and $\sin(x_n)=(-1)^n$. Now consider the sum
$$\sum_{n=1}^N \left| \sin(x_n) - \sin(x_{n-1})\right|=\sum_{n=1}^N 2=2N.$$
What may we conclude? Recall the definition of [bounded variation function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_variation#BV_functions_of_one_variable) and take a look at [Functions of bounded variation on $\Bbb R$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/216233/functions-of-bounded-variation-on-bbb-r)

Answer (score 1):

The derivative of $sin(x)$  is $cos(x)$.  The arc length of its derivative $ \int_a^b |cos(x)| dx$ can thus be made arbitrarily large as we consider increasingly large closed intervals $[-n \pi, n \pi]$