# $\sin x\in BV[a,b]$ for all $-\infty<a<b<+\infty$, but $\sin x \notin BV(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: real-analysis

I read this question: [Prove that $\sin x$ is not of bounded variation, $\sin x\not\in BV$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2427832/1020653) and the answer by Robert Z is:

> Hint. Let $x_n = \frac{\pi(2n + 1)}{2}$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Then $\{x_n\}$ is a strictly increasing sequence and $\sin(x_n)=(-1)^n$. Now consider the sum
> $$\sum_{n=1}^N \left| \sin(x_n) - \sin(x_{n-1})\right|=\sum_{n=1}^N 2=2N.$$
> What may we conclude? Recall the definition of [bounded variation function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_variation#BV_functions_of_one_variable) and take a look at [Functions of bounded variation on $\Bbb R$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/216233/functions-of-bounded-variation-on-bbb-r)

However, I don't understand how I can conclude that in light of the following definition:

A function $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is said a bounded variation on $\mathbb{R}$ if it is in $BV([a,b])$ for all $-\infty<a<b<+\infty$ and results $$V(f):=\sup_{-\infty<a<b <+\infty} V_a^b(f)<\infty.$$

In this case $V_a^b(f):=\sup_{\mathcal{P}\in \Pi} V_a^b(f,\mathcal{P})$, where $\Pi$ is the collection of all partition of $[a,b]$.

Could you give me a further suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: Take $N>V(f)/2$ to get a contradiction.